# Duda sobre pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

Quería saber si existe alguna manera de especificarle a `pyinstaller` que incluya un tipo de fuente de letra a la aplicación, o especificarlo a través de código en `python`.

En el proyecto, puedo utilizar tranquilamente la fuente, ya que esta instalada en mi computadora, pero al generar el `.exe` con `pyinstaller` y probar el dicho `.exe` en otra computadora, esta se ve sin la fuente.

### Solucion:

Investigando un poco, me topé con una librería llamada `pyglet`, la misma tiene un método para consultar si el sistema operativo o el proyecto contiene a la fuente. Por lo tanto, cree un bloque para realizar dicha consulta y en caso de que el método me retorne `False`, instalar la fuente utilizada.

Aquí el Código:

```
import pyglet

def test():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if pyglet.font.have_font('Audiowide'):
        test()
    else:
        pyglet.font.add_file('internal_files/Audiowide-Regular.ttf')
        test()
```

Agradezco de todas formas, Saludos.

Comment: flacpu, ¿validaste que la fuente que usaste en tu desarrollo se encuentre instalada en el otro computador?

Comment: @RodrigoN, no, es lo que pensaba hacer, si esta instalado ejecuta, y si no, instala y despues ejecuta, pero no logro llegar a eso que planteo

Comment: @RodrigoN, ya lo pude solucionar, voy a editar la pregunta para agregar la solución y asi poder cerrar la pregunta.

Comment: flacpu, te recomiendo que la solución la publiques como respuesta a la pregunta, y no como parte de ella.